# Cyclic permutation of arguments / list of arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

I work on a triangle ABC and I would like a macro to define IJK the centroid triangle ( I, J and K are the midpoints of the segments BC, AC and AB).
The problem is not to get these points but "how" to get these points.

I can do that :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}

\def\Centroid(#1,#2,#3)#4#5#6{%
\path (#2) to coordinate(#4) (#3) to coordinate(#5) (#1) to coordinate(#6) (#2);}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path coordinate (A) at (0,0)
          coordinate (B) at (5,0)
          coordinate (C) at (1,3);        
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle ;
    \Centroid(A,B,C){I}{J}{K}
    \foreach \point in {A,B,C,I,J,K}{%
        \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);}
    %\foreach \point in {A,B,C,I,J,K}{%
       % \node  [coordinate,"$\point$"] at (\point) {} ;} 
        % problem with \coordinate  quotes doesn't work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I prefer to use `{I,J,K`} instead of `{I}{J}{K}` and I transform my code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\Centroid(#1,#2,#3)#4{%
\foreach \name  [count=\i] in {#4} {%
    \global\expandafter\edef\csname point\i\endcsname{\name}}
    \path (#2) to coordinate(\csname point1\endcsname) (#3) 
               to coordinate(\csname point2\endcsname) (#1) 
               to coordinate(\csname point3\endcsname) (#2);}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path coordinate (A) at (0,0)
          coordinate (B) at (5,0)
          coordinate (C) at (1,3);        
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle ;
    \Centroid(A,B,C){I,J,K}
    \foreach \point in {A,B,C,I,J,K}{%
        \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I get the good result but ...it's not funny to code if I want to work with four points or more points. The problem is to parse #4 (the list of points) and to use the cyclic permutations to get the midpoints (#1#2  #2#3  #3#1 etc).
I search an idea to improve this code and to be able to generalize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a bit of fooling around it is possible to write the parser using `\pgfkeys`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}%
\makeatletter
\def\atchar{@}
\pgfkeys{/Centroid/.code args={(#1)#2}{\pgfkeys{/Centroid ..={(#1,#1)(#2,@)}}},
Centroid ../.code args={(#1,#2,#3)(#4,#5)}{%
  \pgfcoordinate{#4}{%
    \pgfpointscale{0.5}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
      {\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}}}%
  \def\tmp{#5}\ifx\tmp\atchar\else%
    \pgfkeys{/Centroid ..={(#2,#3)(#5)}}%
  \fi%
}}
\def\Centroid(#1)#2{\pgfkeys{/Centroid={(#1)#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [gray, thick] (0, 0) coordinate (A) -- (5, 0) coordinate (B) --
      (1, 3) coordinate (C) -- cycle;        
\Centroid(A,B,C){I,J,K}
\foreach \point in {A,B,C,I,J,K}
  \fill [fill=red] (\point) circle [radius=2pt] node [above] {\point};

\draw [gray, thick, shift=(270:5)]  
  (1, 0) coordinate (A) -- (5, 1) coordinate (B) --
  (3, 4) coordinate (C) -- (0, 3) coordinate (D) -- cycle; 
\Centroid(A,B,C,D){I,J,K,L}
\foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,I,J,K,L}
  \fill [fill=blue] (\point) circle [radius=2pt] node [above] {\point};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to create the parser without `pgfkeys`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@stop{\@stop} 
\def\Centroid(#1)#2{\@Centroid(#1,#1)(#2,\@stop)}
\def\@Centroid(#1,#2,#3)(#4,#5){%
  \pgfcoordinate{#4}{%
    \pgfpointscale{0.5}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
      {\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}}}%
  \def\@tmp{#5}%
  \ifx\@tmp\@stop%
  \else%
    \@Centroid(#2,#3)(#5)%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, as usual very very interesting answer ! but I need some time to understand each part of the code. I did not want but eventually I begin to define a parser with tex ... pgfkeys is not easy to use (for me) but it's vert powerful

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if that answers.

(Turns out I had misunderstood OP's query and that mid points names are not to be generated automatically; update at bottom adds pure TeX approach to handle this, with names of mid-points already given. Not knowing TikZ I only provide tool to generate the `\path` as in OP.)

I wanted to use more of TikZ own toos but for example discovered that `\foreach \point in {\foo}` did not give naively expected result if `\foo` expands to comma separated names, but some error message from the TikZ parser, hence I again used an `\xintFor` loop rather.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter
\def\GetMidPoints@a #1{,midpoint#1}
\def\GetMidPoints@b #1{to coordinate(midpoint#1) (#1)}

\def\GetMidPoints(#1,#2){%
% #1=first point, #2=next points, ending again with first point
% define labels for MidPoints
    \fdef\MyPoints {\xintCSVtoList{#2}}%
    \fdef\MidPoints{\xintApplyUnbraced\GetMidPoints@a\MyPoints}%
    \fdef\MidPoints{\expandafter\@gobble\MidPoints}%
% apparently this lets TikZ computes mid point coordinates
    \path (#1) \xintApplyUnbraced\GetMidPoints@b\MyPoints;
             }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path coordinate (A) at (0,0)
          coordinate (B) at (5,0)
          coordinate (C) at (2,3)
          coordinate (D) at (1,4)
          coordinate (E) at (0,1);   
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle ;
    \GetMidPoints(A,B,C,D,E,A)%
    \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E}{%
        \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);}%
    \xintFor #1 in \MidPoints \do {%
        \fill [red,opacity=.5] (#1) circle (2pt);}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is pure TeX approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\Centroid(#1)#2{\Centroid@a #1;#2,\relax,;}%
\def\Centroid@a #1#2,#3;{\path (#1#2)\Centroid@b #3,#1#2,\relax,;}%
\def\Centroid@b #1#2,#3;#4#5,{\if\relax#1\expandafter\Centroid@end\fi
         to coordinate(#4#5) (#1#2) \Centroid@b #3;}
\def\Centroid@end #1;{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path coordinate (A) at (0,0)
          coordinate (B) at (5,0)
          coordinate (C) at (2,3)
          coordinate (D) at (1,7)
          coordinate (E) at (0,1);   
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle ;
    \Centroid(A,B,C,D,E){I,J,K,L,M}%
    \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E}
        \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle [radius=2pt] node [below left] {\point};
    \foreach \point in {I,J,K,L,M}
        \fill [red,opacity=.5] (\point) circle [radius=2pt] node [above right] {\point};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I prefer to avoid a new package (here xinttools). I prefer to use only TeX, but xinttools is interesting

Comment: Another problem i need to respect the syntaxe in my package to give the reals points like this (A,B,C,D,E) and I need to give the midpoints like this {M1,M2,M3, etc...} curly braces

Comment: In the current version of my answer, macro `\MidPoints` holds  `midpointB,midpointC,midpointD,midpointE,midpointA` but I couldn't use it in `\foreach\point in {\MidPoints}...` there is probably a work-around but I don't know TikZ syntax. Here it does not expand (or not in a naive way) whereas in the `\path` construct it worked to use some expandable macros. Is your issue about _enumerating_ (i.e. `M1, M2, ..`), possibly with the user choice of the letter `M`, or `N`, or ... ? but your OP has `I`, `J`, `K`.

Comment: you need to use `\edef\temp{\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\point in {\MidPoints}}  \temp{ \fill [red,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt); }`. The user gives the name of the midpoints (it's possible to add something in options to get names by default (but I try to simplify my question.

Comment: You need to expand \MidPoints first

Comment: thus, you don't want automatic labels for midpoints as in my answer, on the contrary they are all given by user as in your OP (`{I,J,K}`) or as in Mark's answer (`{I,J,K,L}`) ?

Comment: Yes the user decides

Comment: @AlainMatthes see update. Possibly this is quite like the approach you have developed in the meantime using TeX.

Comment: Yes it's something like that ... I post it when I have a little time

Comment: @jfbu you can use `\foreach\point in \MidPoints ...` (without braces arround `\MidPoints`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun another solution using `\foreach` loops.
(The test part of the code is shamelessly borrowed from @MarkWibrow's answer.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% ----------------------
\def\Centroid(#1)#2{
  \edef\pts{#1,#1}
  \edef\midpts{#2}
  \foreach[count=\i] ~ in\midpts{
    \foreach[count=\j] \A in\pts{
      \ifnum \j = \i \relax
        \xdef\FirstPoint{\A}
      \fi
      \ifnum \j = \numexpr \i + 1 \relax
        \xdef\SecondPoint{\A}
        \breakforeach
      \fi
    }
    \coordinate (~) at ($(\FirstPoint)!.5!(\SecondPoint)$);
  }
}
% ----------------------
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray, thick] (0, 0) coordinate (A) -- (5, 0) coordinate (B) --
          (1, 3) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
    \Centroid(A,B,C){I,J,K}
    \foreach \point in {A,B,C,I,J,K}
      \fill [fill=red] (\point) circle [radius=2pt] node [above] {\point};

    \draw [gray, thick, shift=(270:5)]
      (1, 0) coordinate (A) -- (5, 1) coordinate (B) --
      (3, 4) coordinate (C) -- (0, 3) coordinate (D) -- cycle;
    \Centroid(A,B,C,D){I,J,K,L}
    \foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,I,J,K,L}
      \fill [fill=blue] (\point) circle [radius=2pt] node [above] {\point};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Interesting there are a lot of ways to get the same result

Comment: I did not notice ~ the first time but  today I try your code and I saw it and ... If I understand its use in `\coordinate (~)` I have some difficulties with the `foreach`.

Comment: @AlainMatthes what kind of difficulties ? `~` can be replaced by any macro name, like `\m` (for midpoint) for example. This is not `foreach` specific, you can use `~`  like a macro name anywhere in tex.

Comment: II did not know that. Good to know ! thanks

Comment: I forgot it's an active character in TeX :(

Comment: @AlainMatthes Exact. As far as I know it is the only character with this property by default.

Comment: Yes you are right but I forgot the fact that we can replace it by some replacement text as for a macro.